# how to write palindrome number in java code

Tags: java, reverse, palindrome

```
public static void palindromeNo(int n){
    // reverse number find first of all for find the number is palindrome or not

               // reverse
                int temp = n;
                 int reverse =0;
                 while (n>0) {
                     int remainder = temp% 10;
                     reverse = (reverse * 10) + remainder;
                     n = n / 10;
                 }

                      // for palindrome
                      if(reverse==temp){
                          System.out.println("this is a palindrome number");
                      }else {
                          System.out.println("this is not a palindrome number");
}                     }
public static void main(String args[]){
  palindromeNo(121);


}
```

i write this code but its showns as this is not a palindrome in every time

i am expecting print in out this is a palindrome number

Comment: Try printing out `reverse`. Did it arrive at the number you expected? Then investigate from there. This would be a nice exercise to try out a debugger on.

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you provided details on which inputs it fails so others could think about your solution.

Anyway, the problem statement here is to write a function, which returns a positive result if such a number is palindrome otherwise negative (i.e., the number is not palindrome). I would solve this problem using a String conversion and then start the pointer technique (one pointer from the start and another one from the end and compare these two pointers). If pointers does not match return negative result. Moreover, the iteration length will be the size of the string length / 2.

So the code could look like this:

```
static boolean isPalidrom(int inputNumber) {
      char[] arr = String.valueOf(inputNumber).toCharArray();

       // O(n/2) -> O(n)
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
           if (arr[i] != arr[arr.length - i - 1]) {
               return false;
           }
       }
       return true;
}
```

And then you could just call such a method from the main like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  if (isPalidrom(121)) {
     System.out.println("this is a palindrome number");
  } else {
     System.out.println("this is not a palindrome number");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace this line:

```
int remainder = temp% 10;
```

With this line:

```
int remainder = n% 10;
```

Because the `temp` is not changing so you are always getting the first digit.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check palindrome numbers.
I have solved it this way.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = sc.nextInt();

    if (isPalindrome(num)) {
        System.out.println(num + " is palindrome");
    } else {
        System.out.println(num + " is not palindrome");
    }
}

static boolean isPalindrome(int num) {
    int d = num;
    int sum = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        int x = num % 10;
        sum = sum * 10 + x;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return d == sum;
}
```